# Javascript, I cant pass variable outside of then scope, can anyone give a solution?

Tags: javascript, typescript, spfx

I am trying console log the variable arrItems outside of .then().  any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

```
protected fun(){
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Requests")
    .items.get()
    .then((items: any[]) => {

    var arrItems = items.map((order) => {
    var info = {
      "Id": order.Id, "File": order.FileName
    }
    return info;
  })
  console.log(arrItems) // works
 },
);

 console.log(arrItems) // doesent works
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could omit the `.then()`, by using the `asyn/await` approach, like so:

```
async fun(){
    let items: any[] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Requests").items.get();

    var arrItems = items.map((order) => {
        var info = {
            "Id": order.Id, "File": order.FileName
        }
        return info;
    });

    console.log(arrItems);
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer,  I have an error on let items : Type 'Promise<any[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 16 more

Comment: My mistake. Add `await` before your `so.web....` request! @ArisVang

Comment: how can I get arrItems outside of the scope of fun function?

Comment: Depends on how you want to use it? @ArisVang

Comment: I would like to save it in a global variable.

Comment: Yes but when is fun() called, when is arrItems used outside of the scope, when does it need to be added to the global var....

Comment: Unfurnatly I did found a solution, can you send an example??

Comment: When you can tell me what you want: yes.

Answer (score 0):

The `.get` is a promise, which is resolved async. That means that other code will be executed before the promise resolved.

If you're not sure how this works, I'd recommend reading some posts / documentation like [this](https://medium.com/codingurukul/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-callback-promise-and-async-await-36258d034761).

You could use the `await` es6 tag to wait until the promise is resolved, and then console log the result.

Example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) { 
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(x);
        }, 2000);
      });
    }
    
    async function f1() {
      var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
      console.log(x); // 10
    }
    
    f1();
```